# Grammar for the following language: L = {$a^{k}$$b^{n}$$a^{m}$ : m,n,k $\in$$ N^{+}$ $\land$ m + k $\geq$ n}

Tags: formal-grammars

I'm trying to create a grammar (having the  highest type) for the language:

L = {$a^{k}$$b^{n}$$a^{m}$ : m,n,k $\in$ $N^{+}$ $\land$ m +k $\geq$ n}

I'm not finding any good approach for it. Hints or ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to think of the CFG for $a^kb^k$, and for $b^mc^m$, and then make a grammar for the language
$$
L' = \{ a^kb^nc^m : m,n,k \in N^+ \wedge m+k=n\}.
$$
After that, think of how you can change it to be a grammar for $L$.